# How to extract LST from different points with its coordinates in google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, modis, time-series, land-surface-temperature

I am trying to get from different points the LST values. The code works, however, I am not able to identify from which point it is extracting the values. I am trying to get the header of each point with its respective coordinate as follows:

```
var myFeaturesWithCoords = myFeatures.map(function(feature) {
  var point = ee.Feature(feature).geometry().centroid();
  var coords = point.coordinates();
  return feature.set('longitude', ee.List(coords).get(0))
               .set('latitude', ee.List(coords).get(1));
});
```

GEE suggests using flatten but I am not sure where should it be added, I am quite new to this software so I am not sure if I am doing it efficiently. Here is the hall code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/582bee226138e9e681c1bf29a9873c54

Assets POI: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-ecoli/assets/ARPAV_coord_depuratori

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to not put the points as columns. Instead have something like `Point index`, `Date`, `LST`, and `.geo` as columns.

```
var startDate = '2000-03-05'
var endDate = '2010-01-01'

var fiume = [
  [12.243014870766286, 45.18498509028304],
  [12.243010411665233, 45.18498509028304],
  [12.75231555668666, 45.663500142530424],
  [12.516674361517314, 45.64961004274894],
  [12.344499551641661, 44.835935578021406],
  [12.209825781625488, 45.155381118389215],
  [12.453163385213081, 44.90843610204938],
  [12.851922956018536, 45.672614545083675],
  [12.374839275209306, 44.839395840438875],
  [12.283374194401025, 45.12475155325309],
  [12.25316378476393, 45.06264965288176],
  [12.417490576785518, 45.00289769876559],
  [12.579217712892946, 45.48959074234498],
  [12.296368014870767, 44.95403041032087],
  [12.110726719813705, 45.233308368399236],  
]

var depuratori = [
  [12.324870588804393, 45.15411027458898], 
  [12.27702889360197, 45.17958957800837], 
  [12.380859061631458, 45.346449139428316], 
  [12.616888198592454, 45.507498492175614], 
  [12.555981337303438, 45.416630930908504], 
  [12.742059624263735, 45.55160346069525], 
  [12.258701988272307, 45.429878920138286], 
  [12.257729904242655, 45.429620292277185], 
  [12.257061039084642, 45.429861083734075], 
  [12.258510246927012, 45.42921897318238], 
  [12.3341990282082, 45.08964059155826], 
  [12.313861068303435, 44.9540081148156],  
]

var pointCollection = coordinatesToFeatureCollection(fiume, 'fiume')
  .merge(coordinatesToFeatureCollection(depuratori, 'depuratori'))

var lstCollection = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD11A1")
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .filterBounds(pointCollection.geometry().bounds())
  .map(reducePoints)
  .flatten()

exportLST('fiume', 'LST_Day_1km')
exportLST('fiume', 'LST_Night_1km')
exportLST('depuratori', 'LST_Day_1km')
exportLST('depuratori', 'LST_Night_1km')


function exportLST(type, property) {
  var collection = lstCollection
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('type', type))
    .filter(ee.Filter.notNull([property]))
    .select(['i', 'date', property], ['Point index', 'Date', 'LST'])
  print(type, property, collection.first())
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: collection, 
    description: type + '_' + property,    
    selectors: ['Point index', 'Date', 'LST', '.geo']
  })
}

function reducePoints(image) {
  var lst = toCelcius(
    mask(image)
  )
  return lst
    .reduceRegions({
      collection: pointCollection, 
      reducer: ee.Reducer.first(), 
      scale: 900
    })
    .map(function (feature) {
      return feature.set('date', image.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'))
    })  
}

function mask(image) {
  var day = image
    .select('LST_Day_1km')
    .updateMask(image.select('QC_Day').bitwiseAnd(1 << 2).eq(0))
  var night = image
    .select('LST_Night_1km')
    .updateMask(image.select('QC_Night').bitwiseAnd(1 << 2).eq(0))
  return day.addBands(night)
}

function toCelcius(image) {
  return image
    .multiply(0.02)
    .subtract(273.15)
}

function coordinatesToFeatureCollection(coordinates, type) {
  return ee.FeatureCollection(
    coordinates.map(function (coordinate, i) {
      return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(coordinate), {type: type, i: i})
    })
  )  
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a33841a7760865b0ef71e27411c68ef6